# Python, how can I execute the output in tabular form: ten code-symbol pairs in each line?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def display_code_ascii():
    for i in range(32, 128):
        print(chr(i))
print(display_code_ascii())
```

This is my code. the output is:

```
!
"
#
$
%
&
'
(
)
*
+
,
-
.
/
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
:
;
<
=
>
?
@
A
B
C
D
E
```

But I want to print in a console like this:

```
  32  is     33  is !   34  is "   35  is #   36  is $   37  is %   38  is &   39  is '   40  is (   41  is ) 
  42  is *   43  is +   44  is ,   45  is -   46  is .   47  is /   48  is 0   49  is 1   50  is 2   51  is 3 
  52  is 4   53  is 5   54  is 6   55  is 7   56  is 8   57  is 9   58  is :   59  is ;   60  is <   61  is = 
  62  is >   63  is ?   64  is @   65  is A   66  is B   67  is C   68  is D   69  is E   70  is F   71  is G 
  72  is H   73  is I   74  is J   75  is K   76  is L   77  is M   78  is N   79  is O   80  is P   81  is Q 
  82  is R   83  is S   84  is T   85  is U   86  is V   87  is W   88  is X   89  is Y   90  is Z   91  is [ 
  92  is \   93  is ]   94  is ^   95  is _   96  is `   97  is a   98  is b   99  is c  100  is d  101  is e 
 102  is f  103  is g  104  is h  105  is i  106  is j  107  is k  108  is l  109  is m  110  is n  111  is o 
 112  is p  113  is q  114  is r  115  is s  116  is t  117  is u  118  is v  119  is w  120  is x  121  is y 
 122  is z  123  is {  124  is |  125  is }  126  is ~  127  is  None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# set chunk_size which is number of initial elements to handle per each outputted line
chunk_size = 10

def format_element(x):
    x = chr(x)
    return x if x != '\x7f' else "None"

# prepare initial list elements with output strings
ll = [f"{x} is {format_element(x)}" for x in range(32, 128)]

# split list into chunks using chunk_size
ll = [ll[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(len(ll))[::chunk_size]]

# join inner lists into output lines strings
ll = [" ".join(x) for x in ll]

# print each line separately
for i in ll:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
32 is   33 is ! 34 is " 35 is # 36 is $ 37 is % 38 is & 39 is ' 40 is ( 41 is )
42 is * 43 is + 44 is , 45 is - 46 is . 47 is / 48 is 0 49 is 1 50 is 2 51 is 3
52 is 4 53 is 5 54 is 6 55 is 7 56 is 8 57 is 9 58 is : 59 is ; 60 is < 61 is =
62 is > 63 is ? 64 is @ 65 is A 66 is B 67 is C 68 is D 69 is E 70 is F 71 is G
72 is H 73 is I 74 is J 75 is K 76 is L 77 is M 78 is N 79 is O 80 is P 81 is Q
82 is R 83 is S 84 is T 85 is U 86 is V 87 is W 88 is X 89 is Y 90 is Z 91 is [
92 is \ 93 is ] 94 is ^ 95 is _ 96 is ` 97 is a 98 is b 99 is c 100 is d 101 is e
102 is f 103 is g 104 is h 105 is i 106 is j 107 is k 108 is l 109 is m 110 is n 111 is o
112 is p 113 is q 114 is r 115 is s 116 is t 117 is u 118 is v 119 is w 120 is x 121 is y
122 is z 123 is { 124 is | 125 is } 126 is ~ 127 is None
```